# Regex for finding list of numbers in a sentence

Tags: java, regex

I have a sentence as such:

"A list of items 1, 2 and 5 containing blah blah blah."

Which could also be something like:

"According to items 2 through 11 there will be blah blah."

Is there an easy regex to grab these numbers?  Also, I would need to know whether it was "1 and 5" or "1 through 5" so I could fill in the other numbers if necessary.

Comment: As written in the regex tag, you should put a tag of the name of the language you are using.

Comment: How about "1, 4, 6 to 9, 10 and 11, 15 - 20 (except 17) and 30 through 40" - how complicated is this going to get?

Comment: I don't see the difference between `1, 2` and `1 and 2`.

Comment: @Tim, not that complicated.  Really just the simple examples I gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression pattern `(?i)(\\d+)(?:(?:(?:\\s*)(,|and|through)(?:\\s*))|.*$)`.  The following sample code:

```
final String ps = "(?i)(\\d+)(?:(?:(?:\\s*)(,|and|through)(?:\\s*))|.*$)";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ps);
for (String s : new String[] {
        "A list of items 1, 2 and 5 containing blah blah blah.",
        "According to items 2 THROUGH 11 there will be blah blah."})
{
    System.out.println("***** TEST STRING *****\n" + s + "\n");
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    int cnt = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(++cnt + ": G1: " + m.group(1) + " G2: "
                + m.group(2));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Will output:

```
***** TEST STRING *****
A list of items 1, 2 and 5 containing blah blah blah.

1: G1: 1 G2: ,
2: G1: 2 G2: and
3: G1: 5 G2: null

***** TEST STRING *****
According to items 2 THROUGH 11 there will be blah blah.

1: G1: 2 G2: THROUGH
2: G1: 11 G2: null
```

You can use group 1 to get the number and group 2 to determine what your next step will be: `,` and `and` to include the next number in your list, `through` to include a range and `null` when there are no more numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extract all numbers from a string by using a pattern such as "\d+", but for phrases like "1 through 5" you need a much clearer definition of what you want to parse parse.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find all digits in string

```
public List<String> findDigits(String s) {
    String regex = "\\d+";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s);
    List<String> digits = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        digits.add(s.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
    }
    return digits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do: `(\b\d+\s+through\s+\d+)|(\b\d+\s+and\s+\d+)|(\b\d+\b)`

Note that the `\s` will match `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`